# AGORA: Display opponents name and Mute/Unmute Button

Tags: agora.io

I am using AGORA open video call integration with one of my mobile App. We want to show the name and audio status (Mute/Unmute) of every attendee in the video call. How can I achieve this?

Code references/sample I am using: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Call/tree/master/Group-Video/OpenVideoCall-Android

Agora SDK : io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:2.4.1

Many thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Within Agora's Android SDK there is the `onUserMuteAudio` callback within the `IRtcEngineEventHandler`. This callback is triggered anytime a user in the channel mutes or unmutes their audio.

Your implementation would look something like this:

```
// Handle Stream Events
private final IRtcEngineEventHandler mRtcEventHandler = new IRtcEngineEventHandler() {
    // remote user has toggled their video
    @Override
    public void onUserMuteAudio(final int uid, final boolean toggle) { // Tutorial Step 10
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(toggle) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "MUTE: remote user with  uid:" + uid + " muted their microphone");
                } else {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "UNMUTE: remote user with  uid:" + uid + " unmuted their microphone");
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

official documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine_event_handler.html#a42ecab512f9fc5ba0785abd9f4d8b2d9

Comment: Thank you. From v.3.0.0, it is deprecated. Use ```onRemoteAudioStateChanged```.